# How to get values in a row that match "True" in a boolean series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

|  | Alice | Bob | Jessica | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Grade** | 90 | 100 | 55 | 45 |
| **student_id** | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

And the following boolean series:

```
passed = df.loc['Grade'] > 55
```

which gives me:

|  | **0** |
| --- | --- |
| **Alice** | True |
| **Bob** | True |
| **Jessica** | False |
| **Mark** | False |

What I wish to do is, get the **student_id** of the students from the df using the boolean series `passed`, save those ids in a **list** and then print out something along the lines of:

`print("The ids of students who passed the exam were: <enter list here>")`

The part that I'm having trouble with is getting the student ids from the dataframe using the boolean series and saving it in a list. Any help is appreciated.

*Note: Syntax for the print statement is probably incorrect*

Comment: `df.columns[df.loc['Grade'] > 55]`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by using the boolean series to filter the student ids based on the passing condition.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Alice': [90, 1],
    'Bob': [100, 2],
    'Jessica': [55, 3],
    'Mark': [45, 4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['Grade', 'student_id'])

# Create a boolean series
passed = df.loc['Grade'] > 55

# Filter student_ids based on the boolean series and convert to list
passed_ids = df.loc['student_id'][passed].tolist()

# Print the result
print(f"The ids of students who passed the exam were: {passed_ids}")
```